# import content of scss file using mixin

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

Is there any way to import the content of a `scss` file into another `scss` file using `mixins`?
Something like this:

```
// media.scss
@mixin media($width, $url) {
  @media (min-width:$width) {
    @import url($url);
  }
};

@mixin small($url) {
  @include media(576, $url);
};

//main.scss
@import '../../styles/media.scss';
@include small('./styles/small.scss');
.menu {
  height: 4rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #202020;
}
//small.scss
.menu {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a `@mixin` in SCSS, you have to use `@include` in the class selector in which you prefer to include those changes or those style rules.

For example,

```
 .menu {
   height: 4rem;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
   background-color: #202020;
   @include small($url)
   // @include (name of mixin)(arguments)  
}
```

or

```
.menu {
  background-color: aqua;
  @include small($url)
 }
```

It depends on the class selector you want to use the mixin with. The
`$url` will be the actual value in this case.

Usually, it is better practice to create a seperate partial file which will include all mixins you have created. These are named with an underscore in the beginning.
For example, a partial `_media.scss` file can be imported in the `main.scss` file as `@import './media.scss';` or `@import '../../styles/media.scss';` depending on the relative path of the partial file.